# Telosb Mote Time taken by Turning Radio off

Tags: tinyos

I am having trouble with telosb Mote, because I don't know how much time it takes when a command to turn it off is executed. Can anybody help me out, please?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's very fast. You can set it to be 192us. But note that if you have a lot of code before the turn off command, the telosb will do them before been turned off. Say if you have an infinite loop before the turn-off, your telosb will never be turned off.

So consider that I think you may be looking for the turnaround time rather than the turn it off command time. The turnaround time is the time the radio switch from the Receive to Transmit or from transmit to receive. The time is 12 symbol. You can refer to the CC2420 radio documents which used by the telosb motes. https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~cs150/Documents/CC2420.pdf